# Do we include preconditions in a sequence diagram?

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

For instance, in a use case specification, one of the preconditions is that the user is logged in but in the main flow it also states that the user logs in.

Answer (score 2):

All **diagrams can show different levels of abstraction**. If you want to focus on more important business stuff, then you have to be more abstract, and forget about trivial stuff such as log in. You can draw a very detailed sequence diagram, or an abstract sequence which explain 5 or 6 actions.**It would be up to you, and your goal.**

But, if the authentication is an important part of sequence, it is better to keep it. For instance, let's say, you want to draw the sequence diagram for money withdraw, then having the authentication is an important part of the whole process, unless you want to focus on other aspects.

Comment: does that help?

Comment: Just to add to this answer, as the precondition of being logged is best shown through states, you can either just show state `logged` in your sequence diagram our you can add `opt` combined fragment with just state `not logged` and a `ref` to another sequence diagram showing logging itself. By such decomposition you do not make a single diagram too complex but show the most important information and you can present all the details of (potential) logging complexity on another diagram if needed.

Answer (score 0):

to complete, in the specification Message does not have pre-condition. But as @Salman explain, you can model a login sequence and use it as an interactionUse.

Here are some schemas: a class diagram to define a LoginManager, a diagram sequence with two gates which defines how credentials are checked, a diagram which uses the previous one. Diagrams done with EA.

[image]

[image]

[image]